# Angular unit testing access component's DOM element conditioned by *ngif after updating the model

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular2-changedetection

I am setting up unit test case for emit event set to table row selection(or click) operation, also I have configured the component with needed data. Here the table is another component, and even upon assigning the needed data it doesn't renders the needed DOM element of table(i.e row elements) to target  the row element for querySelect. I am adding the code snippet here:

component: Typescript

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-user-list',
   templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class UserListComponent implements OnChanges {

   @Input() userSearchResult:UserSearchResult;
   @Output() navigateToUser: EventEmitter<UserInfo> = new EventEmitter();

   navigateToUserInfo(selectedUser: any) {
       this.navigateToUser.emit(selectedUser);
   }
}
```

component: Markup

```
<div *ngIf="userSearchResult">
   <div class="vdl-row">
   <div class="vdl-col-md-12">
   <app-table [headers]="userSearchResult.columnNames"
              [dataset]="userSearchResult.userList"
              tableStyle="list" (tableRowClick) = "navigateToUserInfo($event)">
  </app-table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the spec file code:

```
import { ComponentFixture, async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TextboxComponent } from '@axyz/components/textbox';
import { UserListComponent } from './user-list.component';
import { UserSearchResult } from '../../../shared/models/user-search-result.model';
beforeEach(async( () => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  declarations: [UserListComponent],
  providers: [TextboxComponent]
  }).compileComponents();
}))
beforeEach(() => {
fixture = TestBed.overrideComponent(UserListComponent, {
  set: new Component({
    selector: 'app-user-list',
    templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
  })
}).createComponent(UserListComponent);
//fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserListComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
debugEle = fixture.debugElement;

it('should emit on click', fakeAsync(() => {
    debugger;
    let data;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let spy = spyOn(component.navigateToUser, 'emit');
    console.log("1")

    console.log(debugEle.nativeElement);

    component.userSearchResult = userSearchResult; 
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // console.log("2")
    console.log(debugEle.nativeElement);

    debugEle.query(By.css('app- 
    table')).triggerEventHandler('click',selectedUser);

    component.navigateToUserInfo(selectedUser);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(selectedUser);
  }));
 });
```

And with that ever that I have tried, I get this error in the console when I use "overrideComponent"

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'
    at webpackEmptyContext (./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src_sync?:2)
    at eval (:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core.js?:22)
    at eval (:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core.js?:10)
    at eval (:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core.js?:19)
    at Object../node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core.js (vendor.js:46)
    at **webpack_require** (main.js:79)
    at eval (:9876/src/user-search/components/user-list/user-list.component.spec.ts?:7)
    at Object../src/user-search/components/user-list/user-list.component.spec.ts (main.js:231)
    at **webpack_require** (main.js:79)
    at webpackContext (./src_sync_.spec.ts$?:9)

I have even installed tslib in my project, cleared nodemodules and did npm install, Is there anything that I am not doing right?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do there with your `EmployeeListComponent`. But try changing your code to this:

```
let fixture;
let component;
let debugEle;

beforeEach(async( () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    declarations: [UserListComponent]
  })
    .overrideComponent(UserListComponent, { 
      set: { changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default}
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserListComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  debugEle = fixture.debugElement;
});
```

Comment: It still shows the same error. "Cannot find module 'tslib'"

Comment: @SoujanyaJ can you post the import statements from your spec file?

Comment: Please have a look at the code, I did update the imports.

Comment: @SoujanyaJ Why do you add the `TextboxComponent` as a provider? Does not look like you need it at all, and definitely not as a provider, perhaps as a declaration. Also, you should only add one schema. Try with the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`

Comment: I could overcome the "tslib error" in the console by removing TextboxComponent and also changing the "overrideComponent()" method syntax. Thank you so much for that. I still facing issues with the table not reading the data via inputs, but I guess that's something to do with table component properties.

Comment: @SoujanyaJ I suggest you have a look at using a [testHost](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-inside-a-test-host) component. This way you don't need to use the `overrideComponent`, and can control the inputs of your table from the test host